# CheckBox ASP.NET MVC jQuery change detect not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables, input-type-file

I have this MVC structure accessing the data from the model in a datatable. Each row consists of two td, one td is displaying text from the model's status field and another td is displaying checkbox value as a toggle from the model's isactive field. I wanted to use jQuery to detect the checkbox change and capture the data of the whole row in an array like [status,isactive] . Unfortunately I cannot detect the checkbox value whenever it is getting clicked. Using the .prop() always gives false values, it doesn't change with change of checkbox checking.

Mapping.cshtml:

```
<div id="StatusDiv" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 form-horizontal">
  <table id="StatusTable" class="table table-striped table-condensed acccDataTables">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="StatusCol">Status</th>
        <th id="ActiveCol">Is Active</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyStatus">
      @foreach (var item in Model.xStatuses) {
        var chkid = "chk" + item.IsActive;
        var tdid = "td" + item.AgentStatus;
        <tr id="statusRow">
          <td id="@tdid">@item.AgentStatus</td>
          <td><input id="@chkid" type="checkbox" checked="@item.IsActive" 
               data-role="flipswitch" class="StatusToggle checkbox-based-flipswitch" />
            <br />
          </td>
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button hidden class="btn btn-success btn-save-edit" id="saveStatusEdit">
    <i>`save`</i>Save Settings
  </button>
```

Edit.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rows_selected = [];
    var table = $("#StatusTable").DataTable({dom:'tpli',     
    fnInitComplete : function() {
      if ($(this).find('tbody tr').length<=1) {                 
        $(this).parent().hide();
      },
      fnDrawCallback: function() {
        hideStatusBasics();
      }
    });
    $('#StatusTable').on('click', 'td,input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
      alert("Hey");
      var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
      var changeit = $('#StatusTable input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked');
      console.log(changeit);// Get row data
      var data = table.row($row).data()[1];
      console.log(data);/* Get row ID
      var rowId = data[0]; // Determine whether row ID is in the list of selected row IDs
      var index = $.inArray(rowId, rows_selected); // If checkbox is checked and row ID is not in list of selected row IDs
      if (this.checked && index === -1) {
        rows_selected.push(rowId);
        // Otherwise, if checkbox is not checked and row ID is in list of selected row IDs
      } else if (!this.checked && index !== -1) {
        rows_selected.splice(index, 1);
      }// Prevent click event from propagating to parent
      e.stopPropagation();*/
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#StatusTable input[type="checkbox"]')` is an array,you can get all the checkboxes in `StatusTable` with the code.If you want to detect the checkbox whenever it is getting clicked.You can try to use:

```
 var changeit = $(this).prop('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to code like this, I hope it helps.

```
 var arrayUserRights = [];
        $("table#tblUserRights > tbody > tr").each(function (index, value) {
            var PageId = $('td:eq(0)', this).text();
            var PageName= $('td:eq(1)', this).text();
            var ObjView = $('td:eq(2) input[type=checkbox]', this).prop("checked");
            var ObjEdit = $('td:eq(3) input[type=checkbox]', this).prop("checked");
            var ObjDelete = $('td:eq(4) input[type=checkbox]', this).prop("checked");
            arrayUserRights.push({
                PageId: PageId,
                PageName: PageName,
                View: ObjView,
                Edit: ObjEdit,
                Delete: ObjDelete
            });
        });
```